# What do you call the unfortunate incident where a woman stains her pants in public?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Those times when a lady covers her back to hide period stains.

Comment: Do we actually need one word for this? Or indeed for when men stain their pants?

Comment: @DavidGarner It would actually be useful to have a nice simple term that was commonly understood. I'd much rather be able to tell someone 'I need to nip home and change, I've had a bit of a xxxx' than have to explicitly describe that menstrual blood has escaped my best attempts to contain it. But I'm not aware that there is a word or term in common use. To another woman I might say 'I've had a leak' and convey by anguished/embarrassed mugging that I don't mean I've peed myself, but that would probably be lost on many men.

Comment: I think "accident" is probably the most common informal term.  It would apply to both urine and blood leakage (and possibly fecal "issues"), and would be used by both men and women.  One major advantage of the term is it's lack of specificity, so others can pretend (within limits) that the individual simply spilled something on their clothing.

Comment: @HotLicks I would *never* use 'accident' to denote a menstrual leak, precisely because I would expect it to be understood as a continence reference. A menstrual leak isn't a continence issue, it's a failure of containment of a flow which can't be bodily controlled.

Answer (score 1):

I've read and used the term 'spotting'.
Although this is 'officially' used for bleeding outside the expected period the meaning can easily be expandedfor those situations.

http://americanpregnancy.org/pregnancy-concerns/spotting-during-pregnancy/